# couchdb get value of variable keys with view mapper

Tags: couchdb

I am a new user of CouchDB and have tried to use the official documentation to answer my question, but have so far failed to find a method for performing what should be a simple operation.

I know that one can obtain the value of a known key, say "tacos", from a document "doc" via "doc.tacos". I need to access the value of a *variable* key in a view mapper. I am looking for a code solution that does something like

```
"get-key-value": {
   "map": "function(doc) { var key; \** get key id **\ emit(key,doc.getValue(key)); }"
}
```

I need to figure out how to perform the "doc.getValue(key)" part of this query. If I knew that the key variable was always going to be "tacos", then I could use "doc.tacos", but I'm dealing with a situation where I may want different keys depending on the situation. It seems like there should be a simple method for doing this, but I've not managed to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking procedurally. CDB is designed with a different mindset - one that sacrifices view size for read performance. You emit ALL keys to a view and then at query time can find any key you want (warning pseudo code ahead):

```js
function(doc){
  for (var fieldName in doc){
    emit(fieldName, doc[fieldName]);
  }
}
```

Now when you access the view for given key (and optionally value) you will get all the docs carrying that key. You might have to filter them based on some external logic to find the subset of interest?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. A view function can only access the values of a single doc. Is [show](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List) function what you need? You can pass in a variable to show and access it via a `req` parameter.

**Edit**

Okay I see what you mean. I don't have anything to add that helps you find a solution but I have a couple of things to say. I hope it helps you.

When you create a couchdb view you create a querying mechanism for your data. This mechanism is very specific. For example:-

```
function(doc){
emit(doc.time,null);
}
```

The map function above creates a view that indexes your data sorted by the `key` time. You know **before hand** that you will query this view by `time` value. This is the way all couchdb views work. So what I am trying to say is that even if you do manage to find a way to get value for your key how would you then query it?

Taking your example :

"get-key-value": {
   "map": "function(doc) { var key; ** get key id **\ emit(key,doc.getValue(key)); }"
}

Suppose this key is = `doc.name` and you find a way to execute `getValue()` function. What use is this view to you? When you query it

`/get-key-value?key=`

What do you put in the key parameter?

Now I assume that your documents are flexible. One document may contain a field and another document may not have that field and you want to index only those documents that contain a certain field. The easiest way to do that is to use `if` statement.

"get-key-value": {
   "map": "function(doc) { var key; ** get key id **\ if(key) emit(key,doc.getValue(key)); }"
}

This way `get-key-value view` will only emit when a specific key exists and thus index only those documents which contain that key.

Comment: I only need to access values of a single doc. I am trying to figure out the syntax for accessing these values if I don't know the name of the key prior to execution. I.e. I need the syntax for querying "doc.getValue(key)", which is not a legal method in couchDB.